# Finding the dimension of real symmetric matrices with trace zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the dimension of the vector space of all symmetric matrices of order $n\times n$ $(n\geq 2)$ with real entries and trace equal to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of how you normally calculate the dimension of the space of symmetric matrices. The only difference comes in choosing elements on the diagonal: if I choose the first $n -1$ diagonal entries, then is there a choice for the last diagonal entry which will make the trace zero? How many choices for this last entry are there?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose arbitrary values for the upper triangular values, that gives $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ degrees of freedom, and you can choose arbitrary values for $n-1$ of the diagonal elements, so the dimension is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+(n-1)$.

Comment: dear sir what if matrix have complex entries?

Comment: @srijan: Same answer. The choices have nothing to do with the field in question.

Comment: @copper.hat if the entries were coming from $\mathbb{C}$ and the field was $\mathbb{R}$ then wouldn't the $2$ in the denominator get cancelled and a $2$ woould come with $(n-1)$.

Comment: @Upstart No, why?

Comment: Because then to specify each complex number I would need two reals since the basis is $ \{1,i\}$

Comment: @Upstart I presume that they are taking the dimension over the same field as the entries. The dimension of a single complex variable over $\mathbb{C}$ is one, not two.

Comment: Yes $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{F})$ has dimension $1$. But my point was that my point could also hold if the dimension over the same field is not imposed.

Comment: @Upstart Yes, that is true. But I doubt that was the focus of the ticket.

Comment: Okay. I was just enquiring.

Comment: @Upstart I didn't read your comment carefully initially, sorry about that.