# Dimension of matrices and problems

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the dimension of vector space of all symmetric matrices of order n?

Here I know the dim of symmetric matrices is $n(n+1)/2$.
But that trace is $0$.
So I am not understanding how to calculate it…

Comment: As an aside, your problem statement as you have written it has nothing to do with the trace of the matrix.  If you were interested in finding the dimension of the vector space of all symmetric matrices of order $n$ *who have trace equal to zero* then see my hint below and the hint in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142714/finding-the-dimension-of-real-symmetric-matrices-with-trace-zero?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix is one of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\dots$.

Can you see an example of a basis for your space then?  How many basis elements are there?  What does that say about the dimension then?  Can you generalize to $n\times n$ matrices?